# The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dashboard.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.accessible),
              onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
            ),
            title: Text('Sorted.'),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff0A3D62),
          ),
          drawer: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                  accountName: new Text('XYZ'),
                  accountEmail: new Text('XYZ@gmail.com'),
                  currentAccountPicture: new CircleAvatar(),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Center(child: Home()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.

No Scaffold ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to Scaffold.of(). This usually happens when the context provided is from the same StatefulWidget as that whose build function actually creates the Scaffold widget being sought.
```

The error fires when I try to open the drawer from the icon. Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it has something to do with, well, the context ur providing not having a scaffold ancestor. Try extracting the scaffold to a new widget and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

@rkdupr0n is correct in saying that your `context` variable doesn't have a `Scaffold` ancestor. `context` is currently referring to what's being passed by the outer `build` function, which doesn't have `Scaffold` as an ancestor, it only contains it. So you need to get a `BuildContext` that has `Scaffold` the scaffold you already have in your tree as it's ancestor. To do this you can use a `Builder` widget to wrap the area that needs this context:

```dart
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (context) {//NEW CONTEXT OBTAINED HERE
      return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.accessible),
        onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
      );
    }
  ),
  ...
),
```